# Why $p= -\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

In Callen's book, in page35 he defined
$$p= -\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}$$
where does it come from?
I thought it might come from a reversible process where $ dU=dQ+dW=TdS-PdV$（If the amount of matter is constant）. But for quasi-static processes, does this formula still hold? Why does the formula
$ dU=TdS-PdV$hold for quasi-static but irreversible process?
similar question: why $T= \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$

Comment: have you seen the whole equation of state for dp? that might be relevant here

Comment: The formula holds for quasistatic processes, which is why it holds for reversible processes, because reversible is a subset of quasistatic.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thank you for your help !! but i still wondering why does the formular hold for quasistatic processes

Comment: Callen writes $dU$ as a total derivative and labels the $\partial U/\partial V)_{S,N_i}$ as $P$ since that's clearly what it is for a reversible process. This will hold whenever the extensive quantities $V, S, etc$ are well defined, which they are for a quasistatic process.

Comment: @Harshdeep Chhabra sorry but I don't understand what you mean .Could you be more specific

Comment: Your equation should read $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$; there's currently a sign error. The minus sign arises because pressure is a compressive stress that tends to reduce the volume. In addition, all the partial derivatives need information about what's being held constant (e.g., $T\equiv(\partial U/\partial S)_V$).

Comment: @Chemomechanics thank you for your help! i'll correct it

Comment: similar https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/690543/is-callen-really-being-sloppy-saying-text%c4%91q-t-mathrmds-for-all-quasi-st?rq=1

Comment: @Freedom thank you